# Live shape detection of certain objects of varying color

Tags: opencv

So I'm working on a program that can detect signs of varying shape and color on the ground while flying on an airplane. They are both unknown, but the colors will be more intense than the surrounding terrain and the shapes will be basic geometric shapes. This includes squares, triangles, and circles, as well as parallelograms and crosses.

I've gotten my program to detect shapes, but its very erratic and doesn't only focus on objects that I want it to. It finds shapes within shadows and light and anything else you could imagine. This is probably because I'm running edge detection on the entire frame rather than the object of interest.

Here are my ideas to fix the problem:

1) Detect color, then find the shape surrounding the color (i'm not sure if this is possible).

2) Match shapes the same way this guy matches numbers --> http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/. I see the same problem occurring with this method if implemented into my program. I'm guessing it will try to match everything with a shape.

3) Find a way to crop a portion of the frame that has high intensity, then run shape recognition on that.

**My question is**, what should be my next step? Is there a way to make my program focus on an object of interest rather than everything that it sees? (Keep in mind that I would like to eventually record the shape and color of the object as well as the ascii character inside of it.)

Here's what I have so far.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{



 //show the original image
 cvNamedWindow("Raw",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
 CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

 IplImage* img;

 while(1)
 {
    img = cvQueryFrame(capture);

  //converting the original image into grayscale
 IplImage* imgGrayScale = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1); 
 cvCvtColor(img,imgGrayScale,CV_BGR2GRAY);

  //thresholding the grayscale image to get better results
 cvThreshold(imgGrayScale,imgGrayScale,125,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);  

 CvSeq* contours;  //hold the pointer to a contour in the memory block
 CvSeq* result;   //hold sequence of points of a contour
 CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0); //storage area for all contours

 //finding all contours in the image
 cvFindContours(imgGrayScale, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

 //iterating through each contour
 while(contours)
 {
     //obtain a sequence of points of contour, pointed by the variable 'contour'
     result = cvApproxPoly(contours, sizeof(CvContour), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contours)*0.02, 0);

     //if there are 3  vertices  in the contour(It should be a triangle)
    if(result->total==3 )
     {
         //iterating through each point
         CvPoint *pt[3];
         for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
             pt[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i);
         }

         //////////drawing lines around the triangle
         cvLine(img, *pt[0], *pt[1], cvScalar(255,0,0),4);
         cvLine(img, *pt[1], *pt[2], cvScalar(255,0,0),4);
         cvLine(img, *pt[2], *pt[0], cvScalar(255,0,0),4);
         cout << "\nTriangle\n";

     }

      //if there are 4 vertices in the contour(It should be a quadrilateral)
     else if(result->total==4 )
     {
         //iterating through each point
         CvPoint *pt[4];
         for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
             pt[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i);
         }

         //drawing lines around the quadrilateral
         //cvLine(img, *pt[0], *pt[1], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
         //cvLine(img, *pt[1], *pt[2], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
         //cvLine(img, *pt[2], *pt[3], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
         //cvLine(img, *pt[3], *pt[0], cvScalar(0,255,0),4); 
         cout << "\nquadrilateral\n" ;
     }

   //if there are 7  vertices  in the contour(It should be a heptagon)
     else if(result->total ==7  )
     {
         //iterating through each point
         CvPoint *pt[7];
         for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
             pt[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i);
         }

         //drawing lines around the heptagon
         cvLine(img, *pt[0], *pt[1], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
         cvLine(img, *pt[1], *pt[2], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
         cvLine(img, *pt[2], *pt[3], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
         cvLine(img, *pt[3], *pt[4], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
         cvLine(img, *pt[4], *pt[5], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
         cvLine(img, *pt[5], *pt[6], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
         cvLine(img, *pt[6], *pt[0], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
     }

      //obtain the next contour
     contours = contours->h_next; 
 }

  //show the image in which identified shapes are marked   
 cvNamedWindow("Tracked");
 cvShowImage("Tracked",img);

 char c = cvWaitKey(33); //wait for a key press
 if(c==27) 
    {
        //cleaning up
        cvDestroyAllWindows(); 
        cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
        cvReleaseImage(&img);
        cvReleaseImage(&imgGrayScale);
    break;
    }
}




  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So I've decided to go with harcasscade classification. Here's a video tutorial series I found on youtube if you want to see guys. Thank's to everyone who stopped by and tried to help me find a solution.

Here are some links that may help people that had the same question as me!

[Here's the Video Tutorial I mentioned in my comment.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4N2sH_QTnP4)

[This is a text tutorial that goes trough the process of Haarcascade](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html)